# geth attach issue between mac and windows

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, ethereum-wallet-dapp, cpp-ethereum, etherscan

I am running geth on windows machine and try for geth attach in mac. I give 
below error:

**Fatal: Failed to start the JavaScript console: api modules: Post http://192.168.0.107:8545: context deadline exceeded**

Both machine in local network i.e sharing same network.

But when i running geth on mac and try for geth attach in windows it works.
Please give your input regards this issue.

Comment: Windows machine 8545 is not open i had open  that port try geth attach in mac, it working fine

Answer (score 0):

if I am not mistaken, on Mac as well as linux, you need to specify the IPC/RPC endpoint when asking to attach.
On your mac node, try;

> geth attach ipc:/path/to/endpoint.ipc

You will see this path when you start your network on your other node (geth --datadir...) bottom right the path should appear.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your `geth` running on Windows really listens to HTTP connections on public interface.  For this you need to pass the following options to `geth`: `--rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0`
2. Make sure `geth` allows access over HTTP to APIs you need.  If you need `eth` and `personal` APIs, pass the following options to `geth`: `--rpcapi eth,personal`
3. Make sure firewall on Windows permits connections from Mac to port `8545` of your Windows machine
4. And finally try to connect from Mac to Windows using `geth attach http://192.168.0.107:8545/`, assuming that `192.168.0.107` is an IP address of your Windows machine